# React native | What is the best replacement of 'TouchableOpacity'?

Tags: react-native

`Button` in react-native has too much limit, So I used `TouchableOpacity` (with many decorations). But The button made with `TouchableOpacity` has an delay issue. I also felt it has delay to change screens when it clicked.

So I started to find an replacement, but I couldn't find it. There are `Styled` components, but I don't know it's performance.

Is `Styled` components's performance is better than `TouchableOpacity`, or There is another thing I can use for replacement of `TouchableOpacity`?

Try see [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#js-frame-rate-javascript-thread). it is about my issue.

Comment: have you try ``TouchableHighlight `` instead of this.

Comment: [React Native has declare how to deal with it](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#my-touchablex-view-isnt-very-responsive). IMHO you should used `onPress` of `TouchableX` just to handle `loading` and you can run your `Expensive Function` when loading state is `true`

Answer (score 0):

You can create View component with `onStartShouldSetResponder={()=> ... }` and do with it everything you want. Especially it very usefull with hitslop.